# Cannot navigate to the rpc-controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-web-api

Consider these excerpts: https://gist.github.com/abirdd/9000419#file-setup.

The `default` route fires successfully. If I navigate to `http://localhost:[port]/dashboard` I get this weird result:

[image]

If I navigate to `http://localhost:[port]/dashboard/index` I get http 404 code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it would be helpful for someone. I shouldn't have used the same url for routes as for the css/js bundles. lol!